# How to work with multiple entities in one message in Wit.ai?

Tags: python, nlp, wit.ai

I followed [this tutorial](https://wit.ai/docs/quickstart) to write a [simple script](https://github.com/wit-ai/pywit/blob/master/examples/quickstart.py) using Wit.ai.

So, there is a code snippet which retrieves the entity from the first message:

```
def first_entity_value(entities, entity):
    if entity not in entities:
        return None
    val = entities[entity][0]['value']
    if not val:
        return None
    return val['value'] if isinstance(val, dict) else val
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I get entities from the other messages? So, when user type something (not as a first message)?
2. I have multiple entities in the message (e.g: I'm gonna visit **London** this **weekend**), how can I get, for example, the second entity (weekend)?
   Now I tried to write something like the following but got an error:

   ```
   def first_entity_value(entities, entity):
       if entity not in entities:
           return None
       val = entities[entity][0][1]['value'] # to get the second entity
       if not val:
           return None
       return val['value'] if isinstance(val, dict) else val
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"London" is a location and "weekend" is a datetime. They are not the same entity.

To retrieve both entities, just adapt the `entity` argument:

```
city = first_entity_value(entities, 'location')
date = first_entity_value(entities, 'datetime')
```

If you want to retrieve two values of the same entity (e.g: I love **Paris** and **London**), then you should use the method you tried:

```
def get_entity_value(entities, entity, pos):
    if entity not in entities:
        return None
    val = entities[entity][pos]['value'] # to get the entity at "pos"
    if not val:
        return None
    return val['value'] if isinstance(val, dict) else val
```

I don't really get your first question. The selected action(s) (from Wit converse) is/are run every time you receive a message from the user.

Comment: Ok, I have two entities (datetime and location). I wrote as you mentioned (city = first_entity_value(entities, 'location')
date = first_entity_value(entities, 'datetime') and got the following error: val = entities[entity][0]['value']
KeyError: 'value')

Comment: Did you restablish "val = entities[entity][0]['value']" in the first_entity_value function ?

Comment: I left it the same val = entities[entity][0]['value']

Comment: I put it in gist: https://gist.github.com/ermolushka/a72145b469369b1377861e865b3c5168

Comment: Try to print the entities dictionnary, this will probably show what's wrong.

Comment: I wrote the output in the comment (https://gist.github.com/ermolushka/a72145b469369b1377861e865b3c5168), but I see, that there are location and datetime in the response.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to met that there is no "value" field for wit/datetime when the specified input is an interval. "This weekend" corresponds to an interval. Instead, the field is called "values" and contains intervals.